# Sort html table by id that is stored as varchar in db

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I have a table in database with one of the column that stores ID as a varchar. When I fetch data from db using PHP, and display it in HTML table I want it to be sorted by ID. At the end the records ARE sorted, but in a strange way..:

```
  ID      name
------------------
|AA120  |        |
|AA121  |        |
|AA122  |        |
|AA1199 |        |
|AA119  |        |
|AA1200 |        |
|AA1201 |        |
|AA1202 |        |
etc.
```

I'm using this string in a query:

```
ORDER BY CONVERT('$ID',UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Is there a fix for this type of issue..?

Comment: As for `varchar` the ids are sorted correctly. Did you consider using `int` ids?

Comment: Better to separate out the PK into its numeric and non-numeric components - and what's $id!?!?!?

Comment: Yes, but some ids can have index added at the end of them like A or B...

Comment: So, to further complicate matters, your data set isn't representative?

Comment: Id consists of type of product and it's number they are two separate columns in db and stored as int and varchar...

Comment: Sorry Strawberry, what do u mean by representative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not fetch all the records, and use [natsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) to sort them, then display them?

Comment: Thanks Harry. The array sometimes can get as big as 50000 records.. will that slow the whole process down?

Comment: I've not tested the function this extensively. However, I wouldn't load 50,000 records at one time to display on a page. Fetch `x` amount of records, then use ajax to fetch more, and use the same process to sort them.

Answer (score 0):

You get alphanumeric ("alphabetical") sorting - that's why AA119 comes after AA1199. PHP's **[natsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)** would be a solution for that but I'd rather suggest to switch to a padded numbering such as AA0119 instead of AA119 to prevent further problems when mixing alphabetical and numeric logic

Comment: Thanks proligde but the items are already there and each one of the have an id that i cant change in any way..

Answer (score 0):

> Try this query this works for both only integers and also a combination of string and integer

```
select column 
    from table
    order by 
      regexp_substr(column, '^\D*') nulls first,
      to_number(regexp_substr(column, '\d+'))
```

Comment: Thanks yanivx but the query fails

Comment: yep sorry buddy the functions regexp_substr to_number are supported in oracle you can find similar alternatives I taught of deleting it but could not :( I am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this command @Dims

```
  select col_name from table_name order by len(col_name), col_name
```

Comment: It fails with this error message .. FUNCTION table_name.len does not exist.. I'm new to mysqli so I don't really understand it..